# What is needed to invoke LibreOffice running just the macro without the GUI?

Tags: command-line, macros, libreoffice

Invoking LibreOffice and running a macro via the GUI works as expected producing three HTML files, one for each spreadsheet page:

```
$ libreoffice x.ods

Tools>Macros>Run Macros...

Library: LibreOffice Macros> ExportSheetsToHTML
Macro Names: exportsheetstohtml.js
Run
```

When attempting to invoke just the macro it just hangs:

```
$ libreoffice\
 -invisible\
 -nofirststartwizard\
 -headless\
 -norestore\
 x.ods "macro:///LibreOffice Macros.ExportSheetsToHTML.exportsheetstohtml.js"

$ ps x | grep libreoffice
11286 pts/0    S+     0:00 /bin/sh /opt/libreoffice/program/soffice -invisible -nofirststartwizard -headless -norestore x.ods macro:///LibreOffice Macros.ExportSheetsToHTML.exportsheetstohtml.js
11296 pts/0    Sl+    0:58 /opt/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin -invisible -nofirststartwizard -headless -norestore x.ods macro:///LibreOffice Macros.ExportSheetsToHTML.exportsheetstohtml.js
```

Version info:

```
Linux road 2.6.32-28-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 10 21:21:01 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
LibreOffice 3.3.0 OOO330m19 (Build:6) tag libreoffice-3.3.0.4
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. If you do not close the file in your macro, then LibreOffice will just stay there.

Add a line that closes the file you are working with and it will be able to quit and finish running.